# Selenium Web driver & python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below error message when am automating the website using selenium webdriver in python:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
  (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

I have three buttons. When am trying to click on the second button its failing with the above error message.

Can someone please suggest me a solution for this problem

Comment: Can you please tell me in detail what exactly needs to be done like can I try with any other locators?

Comment: Thank you for the help..Let me try it out